# react js webpack throws error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/content/Login/LoginAuthentication'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I am using web "webpack": "^5.74.0" in my React js project.

when i run npm start webpack throws following error

```
ERROR in ./src/layouts/SidebarLayout/Sidebar/SidebarMenu/items.ts 21:0-83
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/content/Login/LoginAuthentication' in 'E:\project\src\layouts\SidebarLayout\Sidebar\SidebarMenu'
 @ ./src/layouts/SidebarLayout/Sidebar/SidebarMenu/index.tsx 7:0-32 77:14-27
 @ ./src/layouts/SidebarLayout/Sidebar/index.tsx 10:0-40 40:32-43 56:34-45
 @ ./src/layouts/SidebarLayout/index.tsx 7:0-32 24:33-40
 @ ./src/router/PrivateRoute.tsx 11:0-53 135:29-42 148:29-42 167:29-42 234:29-42 259:29-42
 @ ./src/router/index.tsx 4:0-42 5:13-25
 @ ./src/App.tsx 5:0-30 17:33-39
 @ ./src/index.tsx 4:0-24 18:36-39
```

webpack throws this error wherever i import anything like this `'src/content/Login/LoginAuthentication'`

no errors when i import like this `'../../folder1/filename'`

webpack config file is given blow:

```
const path =require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin =require('html-webpack-plugin')
const DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");
module.exports={
    entry:path.resolve(__dirname,'..','./src/index.tsx'),
    resolve:{
        extensions:['.tsx','.ts','.js']
    },
    
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test:/\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            use:[
                {
                    loader:'babel-loader'
                }
            ]
        },{
            test:/\.(sass|css|scss)$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader']
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)/,
            type: 'asset/resource'
          },{
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)/,
            type: 'asset/inline'
          }
          
        //   ,{
        //     test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
        //     exclude: /node_modules/,
        //     use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'] // ?name=[name].[ext] is only necessary to preserve the original file name
        //   }
        
        ]
    },
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'..','./dist'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
  
    plugins:[new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template:path.resolve(__dirname,'..','./public/index.html')
    })
    ]
}
```

*i there any ways to solve this? i can't change imports because there are too much of imports*

Comment: did you find the problem? I am facing the same issue and I don't know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const path = require('path');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
      resolve:{
        extensions:['','.js','.jsx']
    },
      output: {
        path:path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$|jsx/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader",
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
              }
            },
          },{
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
              // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
              "style-loader",
              // Translates CSS into CommonJS
              "css-loader",
              // Compiles Sass to CSS
              "sass-loader",
            ],
          },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader'
            ]
          },{
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif|webp)$/,
            use: ['file-loader'],
          },{
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
          },
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
        }),
      ],
    
    
    }
```

Changing the way the extensions and entry point path.reslove() arguments worked for me.

If you take your attention entry point and resolve extension then you'll be able to observe the difference.

Would be really grateful if someone can explain this behaviour in detail.

Hope this helps, thank you.